# Js ES6, Merge 2 objects and store in array instead replacing existent key

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, merge

i have the following

```
let user = { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', phone: '000111222' };
```

```
let otherInfo = { phone: '123456', age: '30' };
```

**After merging both**

```
let result = { ...user, ...otherInfo };
```

**I got**

```
{ name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', phone: '123456', age: '30' };
```

**Base on this, the phone is duplicated entry, i want to keep the old phone and keep both in array, based on ES6 spread, note: (i can do iterating object, but is better to write less code)**

```
{ name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', phone: ['000111222', '123456'], age: '30' };
```

Some ideas?, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let result = { ...user, ...otherInfo, phone: user.phone && otherInfo.phone ? [user.phone, otherInfo.phone]: user.phone || otherInfo.phone };
```

Answer (score 4):

Merge the objects together, and get all unique keys with `Object.keys()`. Reduce the keys, and check if the key exists in the objects. If it exists in both of them, combine the values to an array. If it doesn't take the value from one of the objects:

```js
const fn = (o1, o2) => Object.keys({ ...o1, ...o2 }) // get combined keys
  .reduce((acc, key) => { 
    // if key exists it both object combine the values in an array
    if (key in o1 && key in o2) acc[key] = [o1[key], o2[key]];
    // take the value from o1 or o2
    else acc[key] = key in o1 ? o1[key] : o2[key];
  
    return acc;
  }, {});

const user = { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', phone: '000111222' };
const otherInfo = { phone: '123456', age: '30' }; 

const result = fn(user, otherInfo);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a generic solution, where you would maybe need to merge more than two objects, you could apply `Object.entries` on each of the objects and create a flat array of the resulting pairs. Then use these pairs to extend the result object. When a pair references a key that is already in the result object, use `[].concat` to silently merge that value with the new value into an array. This also works if the stored value was already an array with two or more previously found values.

Here is a snippet:

```js
const user = { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', phone: '000111222' };
const otherInfo = { phone: '123456', age: '30' }; 
const moreInfo = { phone: '9876543', hometown: 'Paris' };

let res = {};
for (let [k, v] of [user, otherInfo, moreInfo].flatMap(Object.entries)) {
    res[k] = k in res ? [].concat(res[k], v) : v;
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS**
1 line of code

let result = Object.assign({}, info, otherInfo, {phone: [info.phone, otherInfo.phone]})

the **Object.Assign** is more faster